# Error in spring autowire annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am getting the below error in my application and i am unable to resolve it :

```
ERROR localhost-startStop-1 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyHistoryCSVServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
    com.common.application_service.impl.JourneyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl com..common.application_service.impl.JourneyHistoryCSVServiceImpl.journeyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.common.application_service.JourneyHistoryService com.common.application_service.impl.JourneyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl.journeyHistoryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyHistoryServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.common.application_service.JourneyHistoryService com.common.application_service.impl.JourneyHistoryServiceImpl.journeyHistoryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.common.application_service.JourneyHistoryService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
```

My `journeyHistoryCSVServiceImpl` is :

```
@Service("journeyHistoryCSVServiceImpl")
public class JourneyHistoryCSVServiceImpl implements JourneyHistoryCSVService {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JourneyHistoryCSVServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    protected JourneyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl journeyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl;
    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;    
    @Autowired
    protected JourneyHistoryServiceImpl journeyHistoryServiceImpl;
```

and my `JourneyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl` is :

```
@Service("journeyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl")
public class JourneyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl extends AbstractBaseService implements JourneyHistoryPrepareCSVService {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JourneyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    protected JourneyHistoryService journeyHistoryService;
    @Autowired
    protected SystemParameterService systemParameterService;
```

**Update:**

Hi still getting the same error:

```
@Service("journeyHistoryCSVServiceImpl")
public class JourneyHistoryCSVServiceImpl implements JourneyHistoryCSVService {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JourneyHistoryCSVServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    protected JourneyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl journeyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl;
    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;    
    @Autowired
    protected JourneyHistoryService journeyHistoryService;
```

Comment: Hi,I am still getting this error:

Comment: You are trying to autowire `JourneyHistoryService` and no bean in in the context implements this interface. THat is what stack trace tells.
Maybe you should draw the bean dependencies on the paper first. So giusy's question is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, that oyu try to wire the bean to itself:

```
//remove those 2 lines
@Autowired
protected JourneyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl journeyHistoryPrepareCSVServiceImpl;
```

you don't need this

Answer (score 0):

Where have you defined bean of type `com.novacroft.nemo.tfl.common.application_service.JourneyHistoryService`?

Look closely at the stack trace :)

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [com.novacroft.nemo.tfl.common.application_service.JourneyHistoryService] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
```